Type errors on kotlin 2.0 upgrade
private fun read(): Query {
        return HostelsTable.join(Users, JoinType.LEFT, additionalConstraint = { HostelsTable.manager eq Users.uid })
            .join(otherTable = HostelFacilitiesJunctionTable,
                joinType = JoinType.LEFT,
                additionalConstraint = { HostelsTable.id eq HostelFacilitiesJunctionTable.hostel })

object HostelsTable : UUIDTable() {
    val name = varchar("name", length = 64)
}

object HostelFacilitiesJunctionTable : IntIdTable() {
    val hostel = reference("hostel", HostelsTable, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
}

After upgrading to kotlin 2.0.0-RC2
HostelsTable.id eq HostelFacilitiesJunctionTable.hostel started giving an error
Type argument for a type parameter V can't be inferred because it has incompatible upper bounds: UUID, Comparable<UUID>, EntityID<UUID> (multiple incompatible classes: UUID, EntityID<UUID>)

some fields not related are removed for brevity
switching back to 1.9.23 resolves the issue
have there be any changes made that affect the behaviour here in kt 2.0?

Add field definition of HostelsTable.manager and Users.uid to the question

@Komdosh effected that change
